# The result of "tf.subtract" is not the same as expected

Tags: tensorflow

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.random_normal([3, 2], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed=1)
b=tf.random_normal([3, 2], mean=1, stddev=1, seed=1)
sess=tf.Session()
ra=sess.run(a)
rb=sess.run(b)
r1=ra-rb
r2=sess.run(tf.subtract(a,b))
```

Why is `r1` and `r2` not equal?
Shouldn't it be the same in theory？

tensorflow version : 1.15.0

Comment: Do you mean `tf.subtract(a,b)` instead of `tf.subtract(a-b)` ?

Comment: Sry,I made a mistake. It should be `tf.subtract(a,b)`

Comment: can you add your version of tensorflow as well? You are clearly running a tensorflow version 1.x. Consider upgrading to TF2.

Comment: tensorflow version is 1.15.0 . So you mean it caused by version?

Comment: Each session run produces new random values for `a` and `b`. Thus the result will of course be different.

Comment: Just that the concept of TF1 and TF2 are somewhat different (eager execution most notably, the removal of `tf.Session()`, etc.) , and that TF1 will not be updated anymore.

Comment: Note that in TF2, the `random_normal` calls would be executed eagerly, just once, and so you would _not_ get different results because the same random numbers would be used for both subtractions.

Comment: @xdurch0 you mean `a` used in the calculation of `r1` is different from that of `r2`？But I've set `seed = 1`，Why would it be different？

Comment: the seed just implies that the random_normal will always produce the same *sequence* of numbers, not the same number every time. So if you run the script repeatedly you will get the same results, however multiple op calls in a single script will result in different values

Comment: @Addy It makes sense. I see. Thank you for your answer. Also thanks to Lescurel and xdurch0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Tensorflow 1.x` since in each `session` the `tf.random_normal` generates the new set of numbers which is the reason for change in results as rightly mentioned by @xdurch0 and @Addy in the comment section.
Instead, you can set the constant numbers using `tf.constant` and compare the results.

**Tensorflow 1.x:**

import tensorflow as tf

```
a = tf.constant([[5.918868 , 6.14846  ],
       [6.006533 , 5.7557297],
       [6.009925 , 6.0591226]])
b = tf.constant([[0.32409406, 1.2866583 ],
       [1.3215888 , 2.2124639 ],
       [0.19414288, 0.86650544]])
sess=tf.Session()
ra=sess.run(a)
rb=sess.run(b)
r1=ra -rb
r2=sess.run(tf.subtract(a,b))
print(r1)
print(r2)
```

Result:

```
[[5.5947742 4.8618016]
 [4.684944  3.5432658]
 [5.815782  5.192617 ]]
[[5.5947742 4.8618016]
 [4.684944  3.5432658]
 [5.815782  5.192617 ]]
```

**Tensorflow 2.x:**

In `Tensorflow 2.x` since eager execution is enabled by default the `tf.random.normal` will execute immediately and keep the result for rest of the code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=tf.random.normal([3, 2], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed=1)
b=tf.random.normal([3, 2], mean=1, stddev=1, seed=1)
r1=a-b
r2=tf.subtract(a,b)
print(r1)
print(r2)
```

Result:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[5.5947742 4.8618016]
 [4.684944  3.5432658]
 [5.815782  5.192617 ]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[5.5947742 4.8618016]
 [4.684944  3.5432658]
 [5.815782  5.192617 ]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32)
```